# How should one even try to start thinking about quantifying the total emissions footprint for the planet?

Tags: atmospheric-chemistry, atmospheric-radiation, atmospheric-circulation, atmospheric-optics, atmospheric-dust

I was recently reading a paper in which nine planetary boundaries have been proposed. The paper uses modeling and literature assessment to quantify safe and just Earth system boundaries (ESBs) for climate, the biosphere, water and nutrient cycles, and aerosols at global and subglobal levels. It proposes ESBs for maintaining the resilience and stability of the Earth system and minimizing exposure to significant harm to humans from Earth system change (a necessary but not sufficient condition for justice).

For aerosols, the paper defined the safe ESB defined by the interhemispheric difference in aerosol optical depth (AOD) based on evidence that a rising North/South Hemisphere difference can trigger regional-scale tipping points and cause substantial adverse effects on regional hydrological cycles, in addition to the existing Planetary boundary (PB) of 0.25–0.50 AOD based on regional considerations. Interhemispheric AOD difference and its impact on shifts in tropical precipitation are sensitive to the aerosol particle size and the latitudinal and altitudinal distribution of reflecting aerosols. Considering this and the range of these studies (approximately 0.05–0.20 of additional AOD difference), the paper assesses that these shifts may become disruptive if the interhemispheric AOD difference, currently approximately 0.0587 on average and approximately 0.1 in the boreal spring and summer, exceeds 0.15 due to air pollution or geoengineering-related aerosol asymmetries.

The paper also states that a 15 μg/m3 PM2.5 concentration translates to an AOD of approximately 0.17, indicating that the just no significant harm (NSH) boundary for aerosols is more stringent than the safe regional boundary (0.25–0.50).

Thus, I was thinking if someone could help me get started with the concept of quantifying the total emissions footprint for the planet (i.e. what should be its unit? how is different from the carbon footprint of the planet?).

Comment: There are global emissions inventories for modeling like here:  http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/index.php/GEOS-Chem_emissions